# Store our application settings data inside SharePoint custom list versus inside environment variables

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp

We are working on document management system using Power Apps, Power automate and SharePoint, now we need to store some setting for the system such as:-

1. incase a workflow raise an exception to send an email to specific users.
2. when a document is uploaded >> to send an email to semi-collon separated list of emails
3. when a document is approved >> Area manager need to be notified by email

so we can store the above 3 settings either inside a SharePoint custom list or as environment variables inside our solution, So which approach is better and why? i find it easier to create a custom list since it will allow us to define that only certain users can modify these settings.. any advice?

Thanks

Comment: It depends who and how often will be maintaining the system, if regular users every couple weeks then I recommend SharePoint custom list with limited permissions. It will be easier for them work in known environment. Rather then you explaining how to maintain variables in unknown settings, or how Dataverse tables works.

Comment: @Popkornak totally agree... thanks